# Multi-language database birthplace design

Tags: mysql, multilingual

I have a database that has to work with 2 countries, IT and RO.
I have a table called User, that contains also the birthplace.

```
User
| id | name | surname | birthplace |

| 1  | Test | Test    | New York   |
```

I also have 2 tables for the birthplace, one for the IT ones and one for the ROs. I cannot store all the cities in one table because IT and RO have a different gerarchy (region, province, district...). So my first thought was to do a birthplace field for each country, like this:

```
User
    | id | name | surname | birthplaceIT | birthplaceRO |
```

The problem is that every time a nation is added, I'd have to modify the database and the application. On the other side, I cannot make a "birthplace" table because the IT and RO addresses are not compatible.

So, I cannot do this:

```
Birthplace
| idUser | country | city |
```

Because I cannot refer "city" to both the IT cities table and the RO ones.

Suggestions?

EDIT. In my PHP application i'm using Symfony with Doctrine, an ORM, so I NEED the Foreign Key constraint between the User and the CityID!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing birthplace in `User` table, change it to let's name it `birthplace ID` - it can be simply integer but you can do something more sophisticated and use unique codes (your own or maybe there are "proper" geographical codes).

Then you can have table for *each* country specific birthplace and join tables based on birthplace ID. This way you can keep each country specific geographical hierarchy in its own table. If you need to add another country - you simply create another table for that country and join it with `User`.

Comment: So, in the new "Birthplace" table I'd have to make a field for every coutry? I mean, if I have to do "city_IT", "city_RO" fields etc, it's not as different as my first thought! The fact is that i cannot refer to ONE city table, I have a city table for each country. But maybe I didn't understand your answer!

Comment: As I said, the problem is that I have a "CityIT" table and a "CityRO" table, and I cannot unify them, because they have different fields (because of their hierarchy, for example an italian city has a Province and then a Region, instead a RO city has either a municipul/oras, it has no region, it has the exception of Bucharest ecc..

Comment: Let say you have a city A in Italy and city A in Romania. Both have the same name. Then city A in Italy will have unique code IT123456 and city A in Romania will have unique code RO987654.

Then you will have two tables:

`BirthplaceIT
BirthplaceID | BirthplaceName | Country | Region | Address | Post Code etc.
`
`BirthplaceRO
BirthplaceID | BirthplaceName | Country | Land | County | Address | Post Code etc.
`

In `User` you have User1 with birthplaceID IT123456 - so this will be in Italy and you can easily join two or more tables based on birthplaceID so you can get UserID + birthplaceName

Comment: If you just need name of the city or town you can join tables and ignore other columns.

Comment: Ok, I see, but 2 questions: 1, how should I reference the FK of "BirthplaceID" both to table "BirthplaceIT" and "BirthplaceRO"? As I know I cannot do it on multiple tables! Then, how should I generate the alfanumeric id (ex. "IT123456") if I cannot use autoincrement?

Comment: There are couple of different ways: you can create a stored procedure, you can generate them programmatically. It would depend on your actual implementation and requirements. Alphanumeric codes was just a suggestion - you could use anything - I guess that each country has its own unique way of coding geographical locations. I guess that there are international standards too (one topic to research is GIS). However, this may be too complex for your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106895/discussion-between-michele-stieven-and-iaforek).